# Highlight textField in red when user type incorrect input

Tags: ios, swift, input, error-handling, uitextfield

i want to highlight the textField border rather than shows UIAlertController

this is my code if you don't understand my question please ask me

```swift
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

           emailTextField.delegate = self
            passwordTextField.delegate = self
    }

    if emailTextField.text != nil && passwordTextField.text != nil {


                activityIndicator.startAnimating()

                Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        AlertController.showAlert(self, titel: "Error", message: "Email or Password incorrect")
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        return
                    }
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                })

            }
        }
```

Comment: So, what is the problem in this? Don't show Alert, and add border color of textfield, whose input is wrong.

Comment: @mazenqp : use textfield delegate methods to validate input and change the color using those delegate methods.

Comment: i ask how i can do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change a UITextfield border property you need to access it's layer's border color and border width properties:

```
emailTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
emailTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

It's up to you but it will be better to set the `borderWidth` in `viewDidLoad` so it is consistent across all states and only adjust the borderColor in the callback.

In the success part of you call back you will need to restore the borderColor as well:

```
emailTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

You can replace `emailTextField` with `passwordTextField` if that is the one that is incorrect. But it looks like from your view controller that you can't tell whether the error came from email or password. It would be a good idea to also pass back what type of error it is by using an `Error` enum so that you can switch on the error and adjust either the emailTextField or passwordTextField border color.

EDIT:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.emailTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                self.passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                return
            }
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })
```

Comment: please my code in the top, I know how to access there property i need to use this property if you know how show me in my code

Comment: I've updated try answer - is this what you were looking for?

Comment: i think this is the right answer I got n errors but for the text field i use (  textFieldEffects ) it is a pod file it's should work but I don't know what's happening there is no react do you have any ideas

Comment: I haven't used that library before but I assume you are using a custom text field and it is probably overwriting the changes you make to it. You might want to change the border color but if the textfieldeffects you are using is doesn't have a border, then you can't see your changes. I would recommend to read their docs and see if there is a textfield effect that would work best with what you want. If all else fails, then use a normal UITextfield.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
lazy var bottomBorder: CALayer = {
    let border = CALayer();
    border.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor;
    border.borderWidth = 1;
    return border
}()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    borderStyle = .none;
    layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder);
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews();

    let borderColor = isFirstResponder ? UIColor.yellow: UIColor.lightGray;
    bottomBorder.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor;
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: layer.frame.size.height - 1, width: layer.frame.size.width, height: 1)
}
```

}

and use make ur textfield class ur CustomTextField

then use it like this

```
 @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: CustomTextField!
 emailTextField.bottomBorder.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor;
```

Comment: noura if you live in ksa it will be good to contact coz i need some developers @Noura

Answer (score 0):

//here the code which would work perfectly

```
if self.emailTextField.text.isEmpty==true
{
self.emailTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
self.emailTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}
else
{
 self.emailTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
}
if self.passwordTextField.text.isEmpty==true
{
self.passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
self.passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
}
else
{
self.passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
}
```